# Convert android app icons to iOS app icons

Tags: android, ios, icons

I made an Android app. Now it's time to bite Apple.
I have had a little chance of developing iOS App before iOS7 released.

I want to make iOS app as same look and feel as Android app with similar UI components between Android and iOS as possible as I can. Therefore, if possible, I would like to re-use  every design resources from Android to iOS app. So, I wonder if I can generate all the icons, images mostly will be resized to fit iOS6,7 app from Android icons current I had.

I found some online sites it generates all sizes of images from one image for iOS and Android.

- [IOS and Android App Icon size generator](http://www.appiconsizes.com/)
- [Generate app icons of all sizes in a click!](http://makeappicon.com/)

I wonder if there are other solutions or some better ideas to achieve this.
Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally ios devices have retina screens and higher resolutions than android devices. I think you should not do this image resizing operation. If you do this, your ios app won't have a good view because of the higher resolutions of the ios devices' screens. You should make your design all over again for ios app.

You can read [this](http://unitid.nl/2012/07/10-free-tips-to-create-perfect-visual-assets-for-ios-and-android-tablet-and-mobile/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think icons can be resized but other images can be different dimension ratio from Android therefore it is supposed to be re-designed.